# How can you initialize List with the items of another list?

Tags: java, list

I want to do something like:

```
 List queryTerms = null;

 if (tsym) {
     queryTerms = buildTreasuryQueryTerms(event, budgetLevel, null, null);
 }

 queryTerms.add(buildQueryTerms(event, session, budgetLevel));
```

This compiles, but throws a null pointer exception when I try to do `queryTerms.add()` when `tsym == null`. Can you not initialize a List with `.add()`?

*ninja edit*: `buildQueryTerms` returns a `protected List`

Comment: What's a "protected List"? Do you think the visibility affects somehow the returned object?

Comment: I just copy pasted the first bit of the method - sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an instance before you can operate on an object. In your case, `queryTerms` does not refer to any instance (it is a null reference) - there will be no object you can call `.add()` on.

So you'll need to do the following, assuming buildTreasuryQueryTerms() will return a List if it is executed:

```
List queryTerms = null;

 if (tsym) {
     queryTerms = buildTreasuryQueryTerms(event, budgetLevel, null, null);
 } else {
     queryTerms = new ArrayList();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot initialize a list with `.add()`

Do (assuming the object is of type QueryTerm)..

```
List<QueryTerm> queryTerms = new ArrayList<>();
```

Rather than initializing the list to null.

Answer (score 1):

Before you call `add` you must initialize it with `new`, otherwise it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize `queryTerms` as this:

```
if (tsym) {
     queryTerms = buildTreasuryQueryTerms(event, budgetLevel, null, null);
} else {
     queryTerms = new ArrayList(buildQueryTerms(event, session, budgetLevel));
}
```

Comment: This would get rid of any existing items in the ArrayList from `queryTerms = buildTreasuryQueryTerms(event, budgetLevel, null, null);`

Comment: but the question was about initializing the list.

Comment: Yes... but what happens when `tsym == true` if you create a new `ArrayList`?

Comment: thats what the given code is doing. when `tsym == true`, it is assigning a new list to `queryTerms` and after that statement it will anyway refer to a new list. if `queryTerms` is already referring to a list, it will lost the reference once it is inside `tsym == true`.